# Alternative to `adapthisteq`, this functions is really slow

Tags: performance, matlab, contrast, image-enhancement

Does anyone have a faster alternative to `adapthisteq` function in Matlab.

My frame rate goes from 40 fps to 19fps after processing the image of the frame with this function. Any help?

I'm using `mexopencv` by the way.

Comment: It is quite an specific function. Are you flexible in what it does? histeq is probably quite faster

Comment: Thanks, I've adapted my algorithm to use histeq instead. With this I only loose 10 fps instead of 20.